# How to grab data from html files using python

Tags: html, python-3.x, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the snippet that extract links from my html file and I wanted to add some data into the result. I had been trying to search as to how to come up with the improvements but not successful.

Any idea will be very helpful and very very welcome. Thank you.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re, codecs

srcfile = 'sourcefile.html'
URL = open(srcfile,'r', encoding="utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(URL, "html.parser")
count = 0

for a_href in soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile('https://bscscan\.com/token/')):
    print("BscScan: ", a_href["href"])
```

Current Output:

```
BscScan: https://bscscan.com/token/0xd7b0B9d1F011ec19312836F09Ef24a6494da0B8F
BscScan: https://bscscan.com/token/0x6679777D2D59B80302164284a9494a2080350225
```

Output With Additional Data:

```
Name: BigDustin                         Total Supply: 10,000,000,000 BIGD
Liquidity: 5.0000 BNB ($2909.3682)      Holders: 1          Transfers: 1
  BscScan: https://bscscan.com/token/0xd7b0B9d1F011ec19312836F09Ef24a6494da0B8F

Name: SUPERHIT SHIBA                    Total Supply: 100,000,000 SUPERHIT
Liquidity: 1.0100 BNB ($587.6924)       Holders: 2          Transfers: 2
  BscScan: https://bscscan.com/token/0x6679777D2D59B80302164284a9494a2080350225
```

sourcefile.html            #-- local .html file

```
 <u>New token</u><br><br><strong>Version</strong>: V2<br><br><strong>Pair</strong>: WBNB-BIGD<br><strong>Liquidity</strong>: 5.0000 BNB ($2909.3682)<br>ℹ️ <a href="https://bscscan.com/tx/0xba7ed738e744e5899138529a3051ee3b9d2bdc9512ffb8e649d9c291dfe26b14">Transaction</a><br><br><strong>Name</strong>: BigDustin<br><strong>Total Supply</strong>: 10,000,000,000 <strong>BIGD</strong><br><strong>Token Price</strong>: 0.0000 BNB ($0.0000)<br><br><strong>Holders</strong>: 1<br><strong>Transfers</strong>: 1<br><br>⛓ <a href="https://bscscan.com/token/0xd7b0B9d1F011ec19312836F09Ef24a6494da0B8F">BscScan</a><br><br> <a href="https://exchange.pancakeswap.finance/#/swap?outputCurrency=0xd7b0B9d1F011ec19312836F09Ef24a6494da0B8F">Swap on PancakeSwap</a><br><br>➡️ <a href="https://poocoin.app/tokens/0xd7b0B9d1F011ec19312836F09Ef24a6494da0B8F">poocoin.app</a><br><br>0xd7b0B9d1F011ec19312836F09Ef24a6494da0B8F<br>-----------------------------------<br>Our Main Info Channel - <a href="https://t.me/YourCryptoHelper">YourCryptoHelper</a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="message default clearfix joined" id="message473415">
      <div class="body">
       <div class="pull_right date details" title="20.11.2021 03:44:47">03:44
       </div>
       <div class="text">
 <u>New token</u><br><br><strong>Version</strong>: V2<br><br><strong>Pair</strong>: SUPERHIT -WBNB<br><strong>Liquidity</strong>: 1.0100 BNB ($587.6924)<br>ℹ️ <a href="https://bscscan.com/tx/0xcbddd72c16dafd622cb8ba815f68c5139b2d080943a544dfd2eb7f7f1aea86de">Transaction</a><br><br><strong>Name</strong>: SUPERHIT SHIBA<br><strong>Total Supply</strong>: 100,000,000 <strong>SUPERHIT </strong><br><strong>Token Price</strong>: 0.0000 BNB ($0.0000)<br><br><strong>Holders</strong>: 2<br><strong>Transfers</strong>: 2<br><br>⛓ <a href="https://bscscan.com/token/0x6679777D2D59B80302164284a9494a2080350225">BscScan</a><br><br> <a href="https://exchange.pancakeswap.finance/#/swap?outputCurrency=0x6679777D2D59B80302164284a9494a2080350225">Swap on PancakeSwap</a><br><br>➡️ <a href="https://poocoin.app/tokens/0x6679777D2D59B80302164284a9494a2080350225">poocoin.app</a><br><br>0x6679777D2D59B80302164284a9494a2080350225<br>-----------------------------------<br>Our Main Info Channel - <a href="https://t.me/YourCryptoHelper">YourCryptoHelper</a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: You have only provided a part of code. Please post the complete code for us to help. Your HTML code is invalid *(there are no matching opening ```<div>``` tags for the closing ```</div>``` tags)*.

Answer (score 1):

How about starting from the "New token" tag and following along the chain of tags using "nextSibling", for example:

```
for u in soup.select('u'):
    s = u.nextSibling
    while s and s.name != 'u':
        if s.name == 'strong':
            key = s.text.strip() if s.text else ""
            s = s.nextSibling
            value = s.text.strip() if s.text else ""
            print(key, value)
        s = s.nextSibling
```

Result:

```
Version : V2
Pair : WBNB-BIGD
Liquidity : 5.0000 BNB ($2909.3682)
Name : BigDustin
Total Supply : 10,000,000,000
BIGD
Token Price : 0.0000 BNB ($0.0000)
Holders : 1
Transfers : 1
Version : V2
Pair : SUPERHIT -WBNB
Liquidity : 1.0100 BNB ($587.6924)
Name : SUPERHIT SHIBA
Total Supply : 100,000,000
SUPERHIT
Token Price : 0.0000 BNB ($0.0000)
Holders : 2
Transfers : 2
```

Comment: Im getting error: v = s.text.strip(), AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Updated the code to allow for empty values.  I don't have your complete file to test with, I only have what you pasted above.  For anything that can't be reproduced with the material you provided, you'll need to look after yourself.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/test/test.py", line 18, in <module>
    value = s.text.strip() if s.text else ""
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 921, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: The sourcefile.html I am using is exactly the same file I have pasted. I am trying to make further research and testing